# Setting the network using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Do you think these commands are valid?

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/master/docker-compose.yml
NETWORK=testnet docker-compose up
```

The first command downloads the `.yml` file. However, when I try to run the second command, node complains about `NETWORK=testnet` not being a valid. Here is the error printout:

[image]

Is there anybody here who could point out what I am not understanding and make it work? The link to this particular set of commands can be found here:
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-wallet-js/

Comment: Yes, the commands are valid when run in a bash shell. Please show your actual output and errors. It's difficult to debug "something like that".

Comment: Hey @BMitch, thanks for dropping by. I updated the question to include the error printout. So, basically, when I run "NETWORK=testnet docker-compose up" in a PowerShell terminal, I get an error. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @BMitch, ahhh. Nevermind. It runs on ubuntu. However, the compose file is invalid. So, the commands work but the file is invalid. Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

> `NETWORK=testnet docker-compose up`

This syntax is assuming a bash or similar shell. It defines an environment variable and runs the command with that variable exported. It's similar to (but not the same as) running:

```shell
export NETWORK=testnet
docker-compose up
```

Since you appear to be running this on Windows, I believe the equivalent there is:

```
set NETWORK=testnet
docker-compose up
```

Comment: That makes sense now. I was also able to run the code successfully. Thank you for your help, @BMitch!